# Can not pass dynamic value in PayPal button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is PayPal button create order function here I want to pass user input value not a static value present in newAmount state. How can I do it? Because when I pass dynamic value here it is showing error that the "value" : "" & the "newAmount" is coming through a props from another component.

```
<PayPalScriptProvider
  options={{ "client-id": process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID }}
>
  <PayPalButtons
    style={{
      color: "silver",
      layout: "horizontal",
      height: 55,
      tagline: "false",
      shape: "pill",
    }}
    onClick={(data, actions) => {
      const alreadyPaid = false;
      if (alreadyPaid) {
        setError("Already Paid");
        return actions.reject();
      } else {
        return actions.resolve();
      }
    }}
    createOrder={(data, actions) => {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [
          {
            amount: {
              value: newAmount,
              // value: Number(amount)?.toFixed(2),
            },
          },
        ],
      });
    }}
    onApprove={async (data, actions) => {
      return await actions.order.capture().then((details) => {
        // const name = details.payer.name.given_name;
        console.log(details);
        handleApprove(data.orderID);
      });
    }}
    onCancel={() => {
      toast.error("Payment Cancelled", {
        autoClose: 3500,
      });
    }}
    onError={(err) => {
      setError(err);
      console.log(err);
    }}
  />
</PayPalScriptProvider>;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<PayPalScriptProvider options={{ "client-id": process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID }}>
                <PayPalButtons
                    forceReRender={[amount]} // to take dynamic value from paypal
                    style={{
                        color: 'gold',
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        height: 55,
                        tagline: 'false',
                        shape: 'pill',
                        label: 'paypal'
                    }}
                    onClick={(data, actions) => {
                        const alreadyPaid = false
                        if (alreadyPaid) {
                            setError("Already Paid")
                            return actions.reject()
                        } else {
                            return actions.resolve()
                        }
                    }}
                    createOrder={async (data, actions) => {
                        return actions.order.create({
                            purchase_units: [
                                {
                                    amount: {
                                        currency_code: 'USD',
                                        value: amount,
                                    },
                                },
                            ],
                        });
                    }}
                    onApprove={async (data, actions) => {
                        handleApprove(data)
                    }}
                    onCancel={() => {
                        toast.error("Payment Cancelled")
                    }}
                    onError={(err) => {
                        setError(err)
                    }}
                />
            </PayPalScriptProvider>
```

Comment: a bit of explanation enhances the value of a code only answer.